# How to know number of records updated in AD using LDAP

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

I am updating active directory attribute of multiple users in one go.

```
ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(dn, new ModificationItem[] {item1, item2});
```

Is there any way to know how many records have been successfully updated?

Answer (score 0):

In LDAP you cannot update multiple entries in one operation. For example, the method you are using:

```
ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(dn, new ModificationItem[] {item1, item2});
```

takes the entry's DN as the first argument, which means that only that entry will be updated assuming that the operation succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to know how many records have been successfully updated?

Yes.

- If the operation succeeded, one entry was updated.
- If it failed, no entry was updated.

LDAP is not SQL.